# jQuery-ui sortable placeholder not working in firefox:

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, placeholder

When I pick-up and move the sortable item in chrome, a placeholder follows under the image keeping the other items in place.

In firefox, the other items just collapse into the empty space.

here's the code:

http://pastie.org/3648154

Answer (score 2):

I got some help on Freenode.net #jQuery. I had to add display: inline-block; to the sortable items and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the DOM in firebug as you're dragging the images around, you'll see that the placeholder is just an element that tries to mirror the helper element you're trying to drop.  jQuery UI has a way to customize what this looks like:

You can specify a placeholder class to apply to the element.  By default, only ui-sortable-placeholder is applied, so in your case, you'll see an `<img class="ui-sortable-placeholder" ...` element.  here's the documentation on `placeholder`: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-placeholder

Comment: I +1 your answer as the style on the sortableItems definitely plays into the problem.  The placeholder class is still how you would control what the "empty" slot looks like.